# What is the meaning of the verb "to shoot at" someone by using words?

Tags: meaning

I´ve seen many interviews where people that were being interviewed said things that were considered offensive and harmful towards someone. But the question is, in all the titles of the interviews, i saw - Someone shoots at somebody-. Can you guys tell me the meaning in this occasion?

Comment: Sorry, but we need an example, with context.

Comment: See answer by @john01dav. "Taking a shot at" is the idiom being referred to, though the question is a bit hard to understand since it's an idiom and "to shoot at" doesn't mean the same thing.

Comment: Hi @Moises To [shoot down](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shoot+down) may also be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without context, it is difficult to say. But, I can speculate.

I believe that you are referring to something like the following script in an interview titled "Person A shoots at Person B":

> **Interviewer:** Person A, What do you think about Person B?
>
> **Person A:** I
>   think he is a good-for-nothing nefarious plotting ans scheming
>   scoundrel who should be kicked out of whatever he is in that makes him
>   important enough to be asked about in an interview!

Specifically, it means that some person is verbally "taking a shot" at the other person, or, in other words, saying something insulting, or damaging to that person's reputation.

Comment: I had no idea what this question was referring to until you said "taking a shot". That makes perfect sense.

Taking a shot at someone means verbally attacking them. But it's an idiom, and "shoot at" is not understood to mean the same thing.

Comment: You answered my question for complete!! Thank you a lot!!